# How Hibernate Validation message pulled from messages.properties in Spring?

Tags: spring, validation

```
@Size(message = "coming from messages.properties")
private String name;
```

How a message can be pulled from messages.properties in Spring Boot?

Answer (score 1):

hibernate default search message key value in `ValidationMessages.properties` file so add `ValidationMessages.properties` in your resource path

Add you message key value in `ValidationMessages.properties` e.g->

```
coming.from.messages.properties=coming from messages.properties
```

and in your class validation:

```
 @Size(message = "coming.from.messages.properties")
    private String name;
```

Answer (score 0):

It works by implements of interface `org.springframework.context.MessageSource`, these are:

- `org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource` or
- `org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`

You can attach Spring Framework's source code, place break points, then debug to see how it works under the hood.

Hibernate validators get message like almost other Java application. Spring Framework processed it before it called by Hibernate validators.

Reference: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/context/MessageSource.html